# Как защитить сайт от взлома через это поле ввода?

Tags: php

Как обрабатывать `textarea`? Как защитить сайт от взлома через это поле ввода? Обработка BB-тегов и тому подобное! Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

1. От взлома, в частности от sql-инъекций, функцией **mysql_real_escape_string**.
2. Обрабатывать ББ-коды можно функцией **preg_replace**, с помощью регулярных выражений. Или обычным **str_replace**, но это если простые бб-коды, без параметров, поэтому в идеале лучше использовать регулярки
3. Также, скорее всего нужно защитить от хтмл кода функцией **htmlspecialchars**

Comment: А какие bb-коды обрабатывать???

Comment: те которые сам захочешь если захочешь вообще..
а так система контроля пользовательского ввода описана чуть выще

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы "беспробельное слово" не искажало дизайн?

Comment: В каком смысле беспробельное? И как оно искажает дизайн?

Comment: Допустим, в textarea пишем: "яяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяяя" и так далее.... результат будет печальным, если не предпринять меры, понимаете, о чем я?

Answer (score 0):

Посоветую перейти на PDO для работы с базами- при правильном применении сразу снижается вероятность SQL инъекции.
Про BB-теги вам выше ответили